# How do I pass ILogger to a static class, so it's suitable for unit tests as well

Tags: c#, .net, logging, ilogger

How do I pass `ILogger<T>` to the static class `Policies` and its static method `RateLimit(...)`, so it's suitable for both the `Client.TooManyRequestsAsync` and the `PoliciesTests.Test1`? The issue is that I cannot pass `NullLogger.Instance` in the unit tests.

```cs
public class PoliciesTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://httpstat.us/429");
        var request = new RestRequest();

        // TODO: Compile time error here
        var response = await Policies.RateLimit(NullLogger.Instance).ExecuteAsync(() => client.ExecuteAsync(request));
    }
}

public class Client : IDisposable
{
    public Client(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _restClient = new RestClient(restApiUrl);
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Client>();
    }

    public async Task TooManyRequestsAsync()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://httpstat.us/429");
        var request = new RestRequest();
        var response = await Policies.RateLimit(_logger).ExecuteAsync(() => client.ExecuteAsync(request));
    }
}

public static class Policies
{
    private const int RateLimitRetryCount = 2;

    public static AsyncRetryPolicy<RestResponse> RateLimit<T>(ILogger<T> logger)
    {
        return Policy.HandleResult<RestResponse>(response => response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(RateLimitRetryCount,
                (attemptCount, restResponse, _) =>
                {
                    var retryAfterHeader = restResponse?.Result?.Headers?.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Retry-After");
                    double secondsInterval = 0;

                    if (retryAfterHeader != null)
                    {
                        var value = retryAfterHeader.Value?.ToString();
                        if (!double.TryParse(value, out secondsInterval))
                        {
                            secondsInterval = Math.Pow(2, attemptCount);
                        }
                    }

                    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsInterval);
                },
                (response, timeSpan, retryCount, _) =>
                {
                    logger.LogTrace(
                        "The API request has been rate limited. HttpStatusCode={StatusCode}. Waiting {Seconds} seconds before retry. Number attempt {RetryCount}. Uri={Url}; RequestResponse={Content}",
                        response.Result.StatusCode, timeSpan.TotalSeconds, retryCount, response.Result.ResponseUri, response.Result.Content);

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Make them non-static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an instance of ILogger using NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger().

So your example will looks like:

```
public class PoliciesTests
{
    private readonly ILogger<PoliciesTests> _logger = 
        NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger<PoliciesTests>();

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://httpstat.us/429");
        var request = new RestRequest();
        var response = await Policies.RateLimit(_logger).ExecuteAsync(() => client.ExecuteAsync(request)); // No compile time error
    }
}
```

Comment: "nullloggerfactory does not contain a definition for instance"

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding your implementation looks good, but the problem you are getting to using **ILogger logger** in test case. If this understanding is correct then you can just use Mock (using Moq;) library.

Then just mock the **logger.LogTrace** method.

Mostly this will resolve your problem `var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();`

> Assuming you have installed moq library and implemented in the class

// using Moq;

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test1()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://httpstat.us/429");
    var request = new RestRequest();
    
    // Using mock logger
    var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
    logger.Setup(x=>x.LogTrace(It.IsAny<string>(),... like all parameters with type separated by comma))
    
    var response = await Policies.RateLimit(logger.Object).ExecuteAsync(() => client.ExecuteAsync(request));
}
```